# Repeating \alph footnote markers

Tags: footnotes, memoir, expl3

I want to use lower case letters as footnote markers, and have them repeat, so that after z, they start over with a. It seems like a straightforward way to do this is by calculating the modulus of the footnote counter minus 1. Having little experience in LaTeX programming, I thought I should learn the new `expl3` interface, which offers a modulus command. However, I can't figure out how to use the value of the footnote counter in an int expression. The `interface3` documentation says, "integer operands can also be: `\value{⟨LaTeX2ε counter⟩}`; …", but when I try to do this, I get this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@1 
l.14 Some text.\footnote{
                         First footnote.}
```

MWE

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand {\thefootnote} {} {
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {
    \int_mod:nn {\value{footnote} - 1} {26}
  }
  \alph{\int_eval:n{\l_tmpa_int + 1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{First footnote.}
Some more text.\footnote{Second footnote.}
And even more text.\footnote{Third footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Fourth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Fifth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Sixth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Seventh footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Eighth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Ninth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Tenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Eleventh footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twelfth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Thirteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Fourteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Fifteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Sixteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Seventeenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Eighteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Nineteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twentieth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-first footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-second footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-third footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-fourth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-fifth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-sixth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-seventh footnote.}

\end{document}
```

If it matters, I actually want to do this not with the regular footnote series, but with an additional series defined with `\newfootnoteseries{T}`. So my counter name is `footnoteT`. But that didn't seem relevant to an MWE.

Comment: you would get same error from `\alph{1}` you need `\@alph`

Comment: OK, so that's the answer. There's nothing wrong with my `expl3` code, I just need to use `\@alph`. I don't understand why, but at least my problem is solved.

Comment: After thinking some more, now I understand. `\alph` takes a counter name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is from `\alph` as you have effectively `\alph{1}` which looks for  a counter of name `1`.

You could use `\@alph{...}` but the L3 way would be `\int_to_alph:n{...}`

You could use

```
\RenewDocumentCommand {\thefootnote} {} {
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {
    \int_mod:nn {\value{footnote} - 1} {26}
  }
  \int_to_alph:n{\l_tmpa_int + 1}
}
```

but there is no need for the intermediate variable, so

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand {\thefootnote} {} {
  \int_to_alph:n{\int_mod:nn {\value{footnote} - 1} {26} + 1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text.\footnote{First footnote.}
Some more text.\footnote{Second footnote.}
And even more text.\footnote{Third footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Fourth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Fifth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Sixth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Seventh footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Eighth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Ninth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Tenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Eleventh footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twelfth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Thirteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Fourteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Fifteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Sixteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Seventeenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Eighteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Nineteenth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twentieth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-first footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-second footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-third footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-fourth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-fifth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-sixth footnote.}
More text.\footnote{Twenty-seventh footnote.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I decided to use `\int_to_alph:n{...}`. If you add the corrected code to your answer, it might help someone in the future.

Comment: @jcr updated again.